# InboundQueue SMPPSIM

Tags: smpp

Working on SMPPSIM ,

If the size of my inbound queue is 1, what does that mean ?

the message was not received ? or what ?

**please be specific in you answer**

Answer (score 0):

That is the maximum number of messages that can be submitted to Smppsim's SMPP server before it starts to return the error SMPP_ERR_RMSGQFUL (0x14)

Comment: so i have problems ? am only sending 1 msg ...

and DELIVER_SM ESME_ROK count is not 1 will the msg be received by the receiver ?